# Заставить PendingIntent запускать не более 1 копии Activity

Tags: android, java

Имеется `Activity` которая запускает `Service` в режиме `foreground`. Имеется `PendingIntent`. И если кликнуть по `Service` в статус баре, этот `PendingIntent` запускает `MainActivity`. всё хорошо, но как заставить `PendingIntent` запускать не более 1 копии `Activity` ?

Comment: 1. [Tasks и Back Stack в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/186434/)
2. [Поведение Activity в Task. Intent-флаги, launchMode, affinity](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/190-urok-116-povedenie-activity-v-task-intent-flagi-launchmode-affinity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity android:name="com.test.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

Comment: Можно и так, но это [не рекомендуется делать](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)